# Why do I get "Not a terminal" error during output redirection in csh?

Tags: io-redirection, csh

Background:

We have put some command outputs (both stdout and stderr) into the same file under the `csh` shell.

Question:

Why do we get the "Not a terminal" message in the following redirection header?

```bash
> which brarchive
/home/ewpadm/brtools/brarchive
> 
> 
> which brarchive  >& t_0
> 
> 
> cat t_0
Not a terminal
/home/ewpadm/brtools/brarchive
> 
> 
> ls -l Ac >>& t_0
> 
> 
> cat t_0
Not a terminal
/home/ewpadm/brtools/brarchive
ls: 0653-341 The file Ac does not exist.
> 
> 
> (which pwd; ls -l Fc) >>& t_0
> 
> 
> cat t_0
Not a terminal
/home/ewpadm/brtools/brarchive
ls: 0653-341 The file Ac does not exist.
Not a terminal
/usr/bin/pwd
ls: 0653-341 The file Fc does not exist.
> 
> 
> (which tar; file /etc/passwd) >>& t_0
> 
> 
> cat t_0
Not a terminal
/home/ewpadm/brtools/brarchive
ls: 0653-341 The file Ac does not exist.
Not a terminal
/usr/bin/pwd
ls: 0653-341 The file Fc does not exist.
Not a terminal
/usr/bin/tar
/etc/passwd: ascii text
> 
> 
> (which ntpq; head -1 /etc/ntp.conf) >>& t_0
> 
> 
> cat t_0
Not a terminal
/home/ewpadm/brtools/brarchive
ls: 0653-341 The file Ac does not exist.
Not a terminal
/usr/bin/pwd
ls: 0653-341 The file Fc does not exist.
Not a terminal
/usr/bin/tar
/etc/passwd: ascii text
Not a terminal
which: 0652-141 There is no ntpq in /oracle/EWP/112_64/bin /usr/bin /etc /usr/sbin /usr/ucb /home/ewpadm/bin /usr/bin/X11 /sbin . /usr/sap/EWP/SYS/exe/uc/rs6000_64 /usr/sap/EWP/SYS/exe/run /home/ewpadm /home/ewpadm/brtools.
# @(#)48        1.2  src/tcpip/etc/ntp.conf, ntp, tcpip610 2/16/96 10:16:34
> 
> 
> ls -l Ac >>& t_0                           
> 
> 
> cat t_0
Not a terminal
/home/ewpadm/brtools/brarchive
ls: 0653-341 The file Ac does not exist.
Not a terminal
/usr/bin/pwd
ls: 0653-341 The file Fc does not exist.
Not a terminal
/usr/bin/tar
/etc/passwd: ascii text
Not a terminal
which: 0652-141 There is no ntpq in /oracle/EWP/112_64/bin /usr/bin /etc /usr/sbin /usr/ucb /home/ewpadm/bin /usr/bin/X11 /sbin . /usr/sap/EWP/SYS/exe/uc/rs6000_64 /usr/sap/EWP/SYS/exe/run /home/ewpadm /home/ewpadm/brtools.
# @(#)48        1.2  src/tcpip/etc/ntp.conf, ntp, tcpip610 2/16/96 10:16:34
ls: 0653-341 The file Ac does not exist.
> 
> 
> (ls -l Ac; file /etc/passwd) >>& t_0
> 
> 
> cat t_0
Not a terminal
/home/ewpadm/brtools/brarchive
ls: 0653-341 The file Ac does not exist.
Not a terminal
/usr/bin/pwd
ls: 0653-341 The file Fc does not exist.
Not a terminal
/usr/bin/tar
/etc/passwd: ascii text
Not a terminal
which: 0652-141 There is no ntpq in /oracle/EWP/112_64/bin /usr/bin /etc /usr/sbin /usr/ucb /home/ewpadm/bin /usr/bin/X11 /sbin . /usr/sap/EWP/SYS/exe/uc/rs6000_64 /usr/sap/EWP/SYS/exe/run /home/ewpadm /home/ewpadm/brtools.
# @(#)48        1.2  src/tcpip/etc/ntp.conf, ntp, tcpip610 2/16/96 10:16:34
ls: 0653-341 The file Ac does not exist.
ls: 0653-341 The file Ac does not exist.
/etc/passwd: ascii text
> 
> 
> (file /etc/passwd; ls -l Ac) >>& t_0
> 
> 
> cat t_0
Not a terminal
/home/ewpadm/brtools/brarchive
ls: 0653-341 The file Ac does not exist.
Not a terminal
/usr/bin/pwd
ls: 0653-341 The file Fc does not exist.
Not a terminal
/usr/bin/tar
/etc/passwd: ascii text
Not a terminal
which: 0652-141 There is no ntpq in /oracle/EWP/112_64/bin /usr/bin /etc /usr/sbin /usr/ucb /home/ewpadm/bin /usr/bin/X11 /sbin . /usr/sap/EWP/SYS/exe/uc/rs6000_64 /usr/sap/EWP/SYS/exe/run /home/ewpadm /home/ewpadm/brtools.
# @(#)48        1.2  src/tcpip/etc/ntp.conf, ntp, tcpip610 2/16/96 10:16:34
ls: 0653-341 The file Ac does not exist.
ls: 0653-341 The file Ac does not exist.
/etc/passwd: ascii text
/etc/passwd: ascii text
ls: 0653-341 The file Ac does not exist.
> 
>
```

Now I can confirm that this error messages was just gotten only with the which stderr output via >& .

```
>
> which ssh > t_1
>                         
>                         
> cat t_1                 
 /usr/bin/ssh 
> 
>                                          
> (which ssh > t_1) >& t_2
>                         
>                         
> cat t_1                 
 /usr/bin/ssh                              
>                         
>                         
> cat t_2                 
 Not a terminal                            
>
```

So my question is why only the which stderr output via ">&" would produce the error, versus the which stdout via ">" not ?

Comment: On my (ubuntu) system `which` is a shell script. You can check using `file $(which which)`. I suspect there is a `stty --some-option` in  a `.bashrc` (or in any file read by bash on init). looks like your on AIX by the way.

Comment: Yes,  but it has nothing to do with the "which" command itself.

Comment: do `bash -c ls` gave the `Not a terminal` error ?

Comment: No,  so it is a bit strange ...

Comment: Very sorry!   It is indeed my mistaken. Please see my above update.

Comment: If you have not yet solved the problem please add the results of these commands to your question: `type which` and ``file `type which | awk '{print $NF}'` ``. If the second of these commands describes the file as anything like _shell script_ then also run this, ``head -n1 `type which | awk '{print $NF}'` ``. Finally, if that last result includes `csh` then include the contents of your `~/.cshrc` file. (In all cases be careful of which quotes you're using, as I'm using both normal single quotes `< ' >` and backticks ``< ` >`` - copy and paste my code if you can.)